# how to change email of user in sandbox to something like .sandboxname?

Tags: user-management, user-record

I tried to change an user's active email in my sandbox(Sandbox name:stage) as they didn't want to get further notifications for the actions that we are doing in our environment

from : abcd@gmail.com
to : abcd@gmail.com.stage

It sends an email to the new user to verify the change.
If I want to change it to an email like this, so that the user is not spammed with any notifications, what should I do?

Is there any way to suppress the email send to the new email address while making this change as a System administrator?

Comment: Normally a sandbox will update your users' email addresses by appending the suffix to it automatically on the refresh? Did it not do that?

Comment: @sathya I had encountered same and reached to sfdc and they had switched off for us by diabling some stuff

Comment: to save anyone the trouble of looking, DMLoptions through apex can't stop these emails either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this trick from http://www.michaelforce.org/blogView?id=a0D3000000AKmy5EAD for changing a user's email address (works in production too):

> If you change the email address AND check the "Generate new
>   password and notify user immediately" checkbox (all the way at the
>   bottom of the edit screen) then the email address gets committed right
>   away, no confirmation needed! Obviously the catch is that the user
>   then gets sent a new password... so it's not any better in some
>   situations.

Answer (score -1):

When you create/refresh a sandbox, it should append the sandbox name to the end all of User Email addresses by default. I am assuming you changed it and now you need to change it back?

I don't have time to test it right now unfortunately, but maybe try using the Data Loader? That may bypass the restriction of accepting the email on the new account. I don't know exactly how they fire that validation off.